# Redirect after already used response Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to render some page and after certain amount of seconds it needs to be redirected to another page. However, I get an "Can't set headers after they are sent." From what I read, the response should be used only once, though I'm not sure if this is true.  I would appreciate any help or solution to this particular problem.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var message = req.flash();
    res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message'), hassError: message.length > 0} );
});

app.get('/error', function (req, res) {
    var timeout = 3000;

    setTimeout(function (err) {
        console.log('finished');
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log('################');
        res.redirect('/');
    }, timeout);
    res.render('partials/404');
});
```

"finished" gets printed and then it throws error, but not the err specified in callback.

Comment: you're sending the res.redirect twice on your api. your best option is probably to set the timeout on the partials 404 page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use this approach - rendering means sent to browser with headers, then the HTTP request is closed by browser.  You can't send a second response.

You'll have to do the timeout logic in JavaScript on the page, not server:

```
<script>
  var timeout = 3000;

  setTimeout(function () {
     window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
  }, timeout);
</script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you

Comment: Great, also if you could accept this answer would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send multiple responses to a single request. It's like if someone asks you for a burger, you give them a burger, and they walk away. Some time later you lob another burger at the back of their head. They aren't going to catch it.

In this case, you'll need to handle redirecting on the client-side. If this is just a regular page render, you can use the `refresh` attribute of a `meta` tag.

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=http://path/to/my/page/" />
```

If this is an AJAX request, you'll need to have the client perform the redirect after a delay.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect you are trying to send should be done either on the server side right when the user hits the server, or done on the browser after the 404 page has loaded.